# Trying to find a ListBox in order to send messages to it

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

I'm trying to send a message (LB_SELECTSTRING) to a ListBox control inside a (child) window using pywin32. I've gotten the handle to the window without issue, and I also have the thread id and process id of the parent window. My understanding is that controls are treated similarly to windows in that they have their own handles, so I'm trying to figure out how to find the control using its parents handle and nothing seems to work.

The code I have is below and it always raises an exception.

```
try:
    _listbox1_hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(_hwnd, None, "ListBox1", "Preferences")
    if _listbox1_hwnd == 0:
        raise Exception("Listbox1 wasn't found!")
except Exception as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(0)
```

I've also tried using the win32ui FindWindow method with no luck (ie this also fails)

```
try:
    _listbox1_cwnd = win32ui.FindWindow("ListBox1", "Preferences")
    if _listbox1_cwnd == 0:
        raise Exception("Listbox1 wasn't found!")
except Exception as e:
    print e
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Your code looks for top level windows. You need to find the top level window and work through its children. Why don't you use automation?

Comment: I've actually tried going through the child windows with still no luck. I'm not sure what automation is, but the reason I don't use autohotkey is that the majority of what I'm writing is in python (until I can get rid of the bits in autohotkey, then it will all be python). I'm mostly just fooling around to see how much I can do with python since I find the language easier.

Comment: If you'd rather not learn about automation, that's fine by me.

Comment: ok I found pywinauto. I think that's what your referring to? I'll try that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find Python language easier, why not use [pywinauto](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/)? I never saw easier automation tool. And it's very pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

What is "ListBox1"? That does not look right for the list box class name. Use the Spy++ tool to check the list box class name.

Comment: That's what I'm using. If I click something in the listbox or hold my mouse over it it reports ClassNN as ListBox1. That seemed fine to me since that's what autohotkey uses to find controls, but obviously this isn't autohotkey :) I should also mention that "Preferences" is the title of the window that contains the listbox.

Comment: I've tried setting it to None and that makes it fail. If I make "ListBox1" None than it will succeed, but obviously that's no good since I want the listbox control. I haven't tried NULL. Is that part of the ctypes package? The pywin32 api says I can give it a string or None, so I figured if I gave it None it would translate that into NULL at the system level.

Comment: Wait, what are we arguing about here? Because it sure sounds to me like this is a custom list control, and not a standard Windows listbox or listview...